# How to secure a login system

Tags: javascript

I've created a very very basic login system. The code works fine, but if you inspect element you can see all of the ifs that reads the username and password.  My code is:

```
`
<html>
<body>
<form name="login">
Username: <input type="text" style="height:20px;width:150px;" name="un" id="un"
<input type="button" onclick="login();" value="login" />/><br>
    Password: <input type="password" style="height:20px;width:150px;" name="ps" id="ps" /><br>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

`and my checking function is:`

```
<script language="javascript">
function login()
{
if(login.un.value == "user1" && login.ps.value == "user1") {
        alert("user1"):
    } else {
        if(login.un.value == "user2" && login.ps.value == "user2") {
            alert("user2");
        } else {
            alert("Unknown details");
            }
}
</script>
```

Comment: You are not supposed to create a login system using JavaScript or any other client side language. Consider using PHP or Rails instead.

Comment: Basically you are trying to create entire login on javascript which is open information to access from inspect element or view source. You need to handle this entirely from server end. Check this as a PHP guideline : http://phppot.com/php/php-login-script-with-session/

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned in the comments it's impossible to create a login system purely with javascript without the user being able to read the required user + password combination from the source code.

Because of that it's necessary to implement authentication on the server side using PHP, Ruby on Rails, Node or something along these lines.